# how do i send mail using smtp server with phpmailer

Tags: phpmailer

i am using webmail smtp and i was recieving mail before and it stopped working , this is code i have

```
require 'mail/PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
    
    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;                               // Enable verbose debug output
    
    $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = $smtp_host;  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = $smtp_username;                 // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = $smtp_password;                           // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = $smtp_port;                                    // TCP port to connect to
    
    $mail->SMTPOptions = array(
    'ssl' => array(
    'verify_peer' => false,
    'verify_peer_name' => false,
    'allow_self_signed' => true
    )
    );
    $mail->setFrom($smtp_username, $sender_name);

    $mail->WordWrap = 50;   
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
```

?>

Comment: Describe exactly how it stopped working. Error messages? Also you really should not disable certificate verification. I can also tell that you're using a very old version of PHPMailer that's not been supported for years.

Comment: i just noticed i stopped recieving emails about student registering for exam on my website. the error it was displaying was mailer error: SMTP connect()failed

Comment: I highly recommend searching for that error message as it will find you hundreds of answers on here that are mostly the same. Also read the PHPMailer troubleshooting guide which also covers this exact problem.